# Trouble with visualizing components of fourier transform (python fft)

Tags: python, fft

I am analyzing a time-series dataset that I am pretty sure can be broken down using fft. I want to develop a model to estimate the data using a sum of sin/cos but I am having trouble with the syntax to find the frequencies in python

Here is a graph of the data 
[data graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGQEK.png)

And here's a link to the original data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mqZtQ-txdd_AFbKGBlbSL6903CK-_kXl

Most of the examples I have seen have multiple samples per second/time period, however the data in this set represent by-minute observations of some metric. Because of this, I've had trouble translating the answers online to this problem

Here's my naive first approach

```py
X = fftpack.fft(data)
freqs = fftpack.fftfreq(len(data))
plt.plot(freqs, np.abs(X))
plt.show()
```

Instead of peaking at the major frequencies, my plot only has one peak at 0.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWNO5.png)

Comment: The peak at 0 is the DC component (i.e. the sum of all sample values). You should ignore this element when looking for peaks. Either do `X[0] = 0` or `data -= np.mean(data)`.

Comment: I have tried both methods you suggested but neither seemed to have any impact on the shape of the output. Also, shouldn't the x-axis be much bigger given the size of the data? I expected frequencies in the 100's but the x-axis is only -0.4 to 0.4

Answer (score 2):

The FFT you posted has been shifted so that 0 is at the center. Data to the left of the center represents negative frequencies and to the right represents positive frequencies. If you zoom in and look more closely, I think you will see that there are two peaks close to the center that you are interpreting as a single peak at 0. Just looking at the positive side, the location of this peak will tell you which frequency is contributing significant signal power.

Like you said, your x-axis is probably incorrect. `scipy.fftpack.fftfreq` needs to know the time between samples (in seconds, I think) of your time-domain signal to correctly determine the bandwidth and create the x-axis array in Hz. This should do it:

```
dt = 60 # 60 seconds between samples
freqs = fftpack.fftfreq(len(data),dt)
```